# How to have vba execute every 10 minutes?

Tags: vba, excel

I need to have my macro executed every 10 minutes .

This allows it to work in 10 minutes

```
sub my_Procedure () 
msgbox "hello world"
end sub

sub test()
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"), "my_Procedure"
end sub
```

But this works only once . How can I have my macro execute every 10 minutes ?

Comment: add `Call test` just after `msgbox "hello world"`

Comment: Thank you . I saw this before . but i do not understand the logic . It works ! but why ? i cant see any `looping logic `

Comment: it's simple: you run `test` sub. It starts timer and after 10 minutes it runs `my_Procedure`, which in turn runs `test` again. `Test` again starts timer and so on..:)

Comment: Every time you call `Application.OnTime`, you schedule an action to run in the future.  If inside of `my_Procedure`, you reschedule `my_Procedure` to run again in 10 minutes, you perpetually reschedule it over and over again forever.

Comment: Hi I cannot comment due to not enough reputation points. But what if my_Procedure() needs a parameter? How to pass it? Thanks.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You should use this pattern:

```
Sub my_Procedure()
    MsgBox "hello world"        
    Call test ' for starting timer again
End Sub

Sub test()
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:10:00"), "my_Procedure"
End Sub
```

Comment: If I run my_Procedure macro, it works well. However after 10min I get error that my_Procedure cannot run, macro may not be available

Comment: @RockScience, make sure you have `Sub my_Procedure()` defined

Comment: This creates a loop of Message boxes. How do we break the loop?

Comment: @Gangula hoping you've found the solution to your question by now for your sake haha. In any case, see the answer from Gary's student below. You need to enter the same ontime event with shcedule:= False in the workbook_close event. Or create a "stop timer" procedure as shown below, and then call it on the close event.

Comment: @DmitryPavliv What if I need to path a parameter to My_Procedure? Can you advise how that can be done?

Answer (score 15):

Consider:

```
Public RunWhen As Double
Public Const cRunWhat = "my_Procedure"

Sub StartTimer()
RunWhen = Now + TimeSerial(0, 10, 0)
Application.OnTime earliesttime:=RunWhen, procedure:=cRunWhat, _
     schedule:=True
End Sub

Sub StopTimer()
   On Error Resume Next
   Application.OnTime earliesttime:=RunWhen, _
       procedure:=cRunWhat, schedule:=False
End Sub

Sub my_Procedure()
    MsgBox "hello world"
    Call StartTimer
End Sub
```

all in a standard module..............be sure to run StopTimer before exiting Excel

**NOTE**

The "minute" argument in TimeSerial is the **second** argument.

Comment: @GarysStudent this code you wrote above is exactly what I am looking for. However, I have one `Worksheet Calculate` event that the `Application.OnTime` interferes with. `Application.OnTime` only works smoothly when Excel is in ready mode. The `Worksheet Calculate` event in the other sheet is constantly putting Excel in Edit mode thus affecting the `Applciation.OnTime` outputs. Any ideas of how to get around this? I've tried timers, looping, and module scheduled variables w/ no luck. Is it possible to turn on/off the `Application.OnTime'? Any help would be appreciated.