# Excel VBA - Macro error - The macro may not be available - Auto Refresh

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

I have a macro enabled excel file in which I am trying to create a macro to run functions every 2 minutes.

**The following is my code:**

```
Sub macro123()

Application.SendKeys ("%{A}")
Application.SendKeys ("R")
Application.SendKeys ("A")
Call test

End Sub

Sub test()

Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:02:00"), "macro123"

End Sub
```

The macro123 gets executed the first time I run it.
After 2 minutes it tried to run it again, that's when I am getting the following error.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

The macro settings seem to be greyed out, probably due to domain settings of organization?

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Is there any other way for me to execute those statements every **n** minutes?

Comment: You're not specifying which `Workbook` your `Macro123` is coming from. Excel is assuming the macro is in the `ActiveWorkbook` when it's really someplace else. Make sure it's fully specified.

Comment: Consider getting rid of the `.SendKeys` and using `Workbooks("myWorkbook").RefreshAll`.

Comment: @PeterT I have updated the post with a screenshot of the VBA editor. That is the structure of the workbook. Please advice how to achieve this?

Comment: @Jeeped Considering the configuration, RefreshAll only refreshes the cells but it does not download the latest data. Check:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42937961/salesforce-excel-add-in-auto-refresh-doesnt-trigger-a-data-connection-downloa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your macro is in the code module `ThisWorkbook`, then you should specify it including the code module's name.

Try this:

```
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:02:00"), "ThisWorkbook.macro123"
'                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: This Works! :) 
Thanks a lot