# Visual Basic for Applications

Tags: excel, vba

My problem is I have data in F10. But 'F10' data is change daily by some calculation. So I want to store this data in a sequence order, if 1st day of F10 value store in X1 then next day the value store in X2 and this goes on. Basically I want each day F10 value store X1 then X2 etc. Any vba or excel formula.

Comment: Start looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22772898/how-to-have-vba-execute-every-10-minutes) SO question. Update your question by adding your code.

Comment: Does F10 contain a formula ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include this macro to the sheet and run everytime when you have a new value in cell `F10`,

```
Sub F10()
Dim i As Long
i = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("A" & i + 1) = Range("F10")
End Sub
```

Or you could use the `worksheet_change` event to detect changes to cell `F10`. If there is any change, then the value will be updated to the `column A` currently. You have to modify this to change it to `column X`, if required.

```
Private Sub worksheet_change(ByVal target As Range)
If target.Address = "$F$10" Then
    Dim i As Long
    i = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("A" & i + 1) = Range("F10")
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Gowtham Shiva, thank you so much..this works fine..but can i ask you one of my query...is this possible,"without assigning any button can this formula execute automatically". Means while value change in f10 result show in A column automatically..

Comment: @pritom Yes, that is exactly what the second code snippet does. it does that automaticaly. Please mark this answer as correct to make it resolved