# Excel VBA to start shell script in background with specified environment

Tags: vba, excel, shell, wsh

I want use an Excel macro to start a python script to run in the background.

I have to be able to specify that it use the system PATH (I don't want to assume where python is installed) as well as a particular working directory, where it will find other files it needs.

Presently I use the following, but this blocks the Excel process until it is complete.

```vb
Sub RunPython()
    shellScript = "python Daily.py"
    Dim wsh As Object
    Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    wsh.CurrentDirectory = Application.ThisWorkbook.Path
    Set wshSystemEnv = wsh.Environment("Process")
    Set WshShellExec = wsh.exec(shellScript)
    Range("C7").Value = WshShellExec.StdErr.ReadAll ' Show error, if any
End Sub
```

How can I run this on a background process?

Bonus points if there are methods of invoking another VBA subroutine after the process has completed!

Comment: Could you run multiple instances of Excel so you have one "freed" up one?

Comment: @QHarr – Yes, [already found a way to do that by default](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3165211/how-to-force-excel-to-open-in-a-new-instance-by-default)!

Answer (score 1):

Well, the issue here is Excel VBA doesn't support multi-threading, that means all of the code runs linear only! And because the shell should return something that you want to write into a cell it has of course to wait until the python script finished. So the Excel instance running this code will always wait for the py script.

**Suggested workaround**
Run the script with `Shell "python Daily.py"` and redirect the output into a file: `Shell "python Daily.py >output.txt"`

Then run a loop to check if the file exists

```vb
Do
    DoEvents 'make Excel responsive
Loop While Not FileExists("output.txt")
```

eg use this function

```vb
Function FileExists(ByVal fName As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    FileExists = ((GetAttr(fName) And vbDirectory) <> vbDirectory)
End Function
```

Note that you won't be able to run another macro while that loop runs, but Excel is responsive.

Otherwise you can use [How to have vba execute every 10 minutes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22772898/how-to-have-vba-execute-every-10-minutes) to eg. check every 1 minute if the file exists and then run a procedure.

Don't forget to delete the `output.txt` file before running the py script.