# Lock USED cells every hour or 30 min

Tags: excel

I have file that is used by a lot of people. They are entering data from time to time. I have locked and unlocked cells so the people can enter the data but not to mess around with the generated data (like time). I have a code that is locking the cell after every enter but then if someone enter the wrong data it can't be undone if I am not around.

So I decided to create VBA code to lock all USED cells every X minutes (so if someone make a mistake to fix it) but don't know how to do the minutes part.

I found this nice code for locking the used cells :

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
On Error Resume Next
'Resume to next line if any error occurs
 Dim Cell As Range
 With ActiveSheet
 'first of all unprotect the entire
 'sheet and unlock all cells
 .Unprotect Password:=""
 .Cells.Locked = False
 'Now search for non blank cells
 'and lock them and unlock blank cells
 For Each Cell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
 If Cell.Value = "" Then
 Cell.Locked = False
 Else
 Cell.Locked = True
 End If
 Next Cell
 .Protect Password:=""
 'Protect with blank password, you can change it
 End With
Exit Sub
End Sub
```

The only thing that I need is to add a code to execute the above every 30 mins or 1 hour. Don't know if the Sub shoud be `Sub Workbook_BeforeSave` or `AfterSave` for this one as after every entry the file save itself automatically or should be like module.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sub should be in a module and have different name. Then you can run it every x mins using this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22772898/how-to-have-vba-execute-every-10-minutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Ricardo.

I manage to create this :

```
Private Sub save_cells()
On Error Resume Next
'Resume to next line if any error occurs
 Dim Cell As Range
 With ActiveSheet
 'first of all unprotect the entire
 'sheet and unlock all cells
 .Unprotect Password:="0"
 .Cells.Locked = False
 'Now search for non blank cells
 'and lock them and unlock blank cells
 For Each Cell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
 If Cell.Value = "" Then
 Cell.Locked = False
 Else
 Cell.Locked = True
 End If
 If Cell.HasFormula Then
Cell.Locked = True
Cell.FormulaHidden = True
End If
 Next Cell
 .Protect Password:="0"
 'Protect with blank password, you can change it
 End With
 Application.SendKeys "{RIGHT}{LEFT}"
 Call savetimer
Exit Sub
End Sub

 Sub savetimer()
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("23:15:30"), "save_cells"
End Sub
```

The only problem that I have now is that the code is scanning all of the rows and making my file slow when I put it to lock every 15 minutes or so. For that reason I decided to lock the cells one time per day.

If someone have idea how to amend the code to scan only A3:O600 whould be great.